# Dragging away a fullscreen window on Mac

Tags: mission-control, fullscreen, ui, spaces

I have recently switched to Mac after using Linux Mint and still getting used to its UX paradigms.

Is it possible to:

1. Go on full screen with a window by clicking on the blue dot.
2. Then drag the window to the side by grabbing it on the top (while it is in full screen mode)? In other words the action of dragging would take the window out of full screen mode.

Is it possible to make this tweak on OS X Yosemite 10.10.5?

It's just something I am used to do often and I wonder if the only option is to un-learn it.

Comment: Not that I know of. I do occasionally hit the escape button to quickly get myself out of full screen mode if that would work for you.

Comment: Thanks but, Esc doesn't get me out of full screen mode.

Comment: Hmm I just did it with Safari. Maybe it's not a system wide option.